# Get HTML nodes that have the same parent - JAVA

Tags: java, html, parsing, dom, jsoup

I have a document containing several forms similar to the example posted below. I want to extract all the name/value pairs from the hidden input fields of one of the forms, the form is identified by its name and I don't know in advance how many hidden fields will be present.

I am able to select all the relevant input fields in the document using the selector query: `input[type=hidden][name][value]`

Is there a way to only select the input fields which has `FORM[name=lgo]` as parent? Using some kind filter maybe?

```
<FORM METHOD='POST' onSubmit='javascript:isWaitForm();' ACTION='https://abc-azerty.querty.se/carmon/servlet/action/change_1     ' name='lgo'>
    <input type='hidden' name='LogInFlag' value='1'>
    <input type='hidden' name='LogInTime' value='2011-07-26 11:10'>
    <input type='hidden' name='cCode2' value='SE'>
    <a href='javascript:isWaitForm();javascript:document.lgo.submit();' class='linkNone'>Business Monitor</a>
    <a href='javascript:isWaitForm();javascript:document.lgo.submit();' class='linkNone'>
    <input type='image' src='/images/button_arrow_right.gif' height=19 width=22 border=0 style='float:left;'></A>
</FORM>
```

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Has to be a java based solution.

Comment: When you say Java, you mean server-side java or Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this info](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax), at least one of following should work -

```
doc.select("form[name=lgo] > input[type=hidden]");
```

Or, you can chain your selects -

```
doc.select("form[name=lgo]").select("input[type=hidden]");
```

> The select method is available in a Document, Element, or in Elements. It is contextual, so you can filter by selecting from a specific element, or by chaining select calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('lgo')[0].getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0 ; i < inputs.length ; i++){
  if(inputs[i].getAttribute('type') == "hidden") {
  // This will get the name: inputs[i].getAttribute('name')
  // This will get the value: inputs[i].value)
  console.log(inputs[i].getAttribute('name') + ": " + inputs[i].value);
}}
</script>
```

Comment: unfortunately I'm using java and jsoup, can't use a javascript based solution.